# Xgboost n_estimators doesn't match the number of displayed trees

Tags: python, parameters, xgboost

Maybe I'm missing something, I can't figure it, I need your help.

I'm training an xgb model using these lines

```
 XGB = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective ='multi:softprob',
                        learning_rate = 0.3,
                        max_depth = 1, 
                        n_estimators = 3,
                        n_jobs = 5)
clf = XGB.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

When I print the XGB model it says that I have indeed trained 3 trees :

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
              learning_rate=0.3, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=1,
              min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=3, n_jobs=5,
              nthread=None, objective='multi:softprob', random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
              silent=None, subsample=1, verbosity=1)
```

But when I run this line to see where features were split

```
dump_list = clf.get_booster().get_dump()
```

I get 9 lines

```
['0:[f0<0.942677855] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.103566267\n\t2:leaf=0.43779847\n',
 '0:[f0<0.954393268] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.200365365\n\t2:leaf=-0.216199294\n',
 '0:[f13<0.651464462] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.276390254\n\t2:leaf=-0.219127133\n',
 '0:[f0<0.917573214] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.110939182\n\t2:leaf=0.292450339\n',
 '0:[f0<0.966108799] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.135595635\n\t2:leaf=-0.194633663\n',
 '0:[f11<0.6690377] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.202725366\n\t2:leaf=-0.196870551\n',
 '0:[f0<0.899163187] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.107093893\n\t2:leaf=0.230380043\n',
 '0:[f0<0.974476993] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.10007298\n\t2:leaf=-0.180789232\n',
 '0:[f13<0.588702917] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.235898077\n\t2:leaf=-0.177840069\n']
```

Does that mean that 9 trees were fitted?

I've noticed that the number of lines I get here is correlated with the number of classes in my dataset. Here I'm using a dataset with 3 classes. When I use a dataset with 2 classes I get 6 lines. This hints to a relationship between the number of classes and the number of fitted trees which doesn't really make sense. So my other question is what is the interpretation of the output of clf.get_booster().get_dump().

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Part of my question was answered by Ivan Libedinsky. The answer to the following question in the comment is : trees in xgboost are grown in a one versus the rest fashion, that's why it looks like there are 3 trees for each iteration of the algorithm since there are 3 classes in my database.

Answer (score 0):

The format is a bit untidy for 'get_dumps()` Ibelieve (althought not 100% sure) that your trees can be seen as:

```
tree_1 = ['0:[f0<0.942677855] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.103566267\n\t2:leaf=0.43779847\n',
 '0:[f0<0.954393268] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.200365365\n\t2:leaf=-0.216199294\n',
 '0:[f13<0.651464462] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.276390254\n\t2:leaf=-0.219127133\n',]
 tree_2= ['0:[f0<0.917573214] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.110939182\n\t2:leaf=0.292450339\n',
 '0:[f0<0.966108799] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.135595635\n\t2:leaf=-0.194633663\n',
 '0:[f11<0.6690377] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.202725366\n\t2:leaf=-0.196870551\n',]
 tree_3 = ['0:[f0<0.899163187] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=-0.107093893\n\t2:leaf=0.230380043\n',
 '0:[f0<0.974476993] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.10007298\n\t2:leaf=-0.180789232\n',
 '0:[f13<0.588702917] yes=1,no=2,missing=1\n\t1:leaf=0.235898077\n\t2:leaf=-0.177840069\n']]
```

Sorry for formatting, I'm on my phone, will try to fix it asap.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have one more question : do the 3 lines in tree_1, for example, have something to do with my 3 classes ?  If so, can you explain what.